# how to save date type to mongoDB when using spark Stratio

Tags: mongodb, scala, date, apache-spark, stratio

I use the project to deal with data in `mongoDB` and `apache spark` https://github.com/Stratio/spark-mongodb 
When I save `java.util.Date` to `mongoDB`, it says:

> spark sqlSchema for type java.util.Date is not supported

When I change to `java.sql.Date` it says:

> Can't find a codec for class java.sql.Date.